# Can't select hard disk off Windows 7 system image creator

Tags: windows-7, backup

When I try to create a system image in Windows 7 from the Control Panel (Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Backup and Restore) I get the option to select a hard disk or a removeable disk to select, I have 2 disks and wanted to create the image on my spare one. However when I click refresh it doesn't show either of my disks but shows my CDROM under the removable disks area, anyone have this problem?

Also, when I select a USB disk instead, it tries to iamge both my disks! I can't select my active Windows 7 installed disk! How pointless!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind going 3rd party, [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) is a great imaging utility.